# Does JSON structure of a JAXB Object always align with the element ordering defined in XSD?

Tags: json, xsd, gson

Does JSON string structure of a JAXB object, always align with the ordering of the elements defined in XSD? To be more clear, for eg, if I have an XSD as below

```
<xs:schema>
<xs:complexType name="Person">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="header">
         <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element ......>
               <xs:element ......>
               ......
               .......
            </xs:sequence>
         <xs:complextType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="data">
        ..........
        ...........
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name ="footer">
        ...........
        ...........
      </xs:elment>
      </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

As you see, my schema defined a complex type called Person, with a sequence of elements like Header, data, footer so on other elements.
Now I create an Object and then convert to a JSON string.

Would that JSON string always return like

```
{"header":{},"data":{},"footer":{}}
```

or the order could change?

I tested this by creating a Person object, in different ways, but in all the cases I saw the above structure. But I don't want to conclude based on this test.

Is there any specification that confirms that JSON element order will be aligned with XSD element ordering, or does not align?

The whole reason, I have this question is for a scenario, where I'm required to process a very huge (possible couple of GB) of JSON payload as a stream, from top to bottom. I do not want to load the whole object into memory to process it. If the ordering of the elements in JSON is predictable, then I can build my logic around that. If that ordering is not predictable, then I have to revisit on how to process such a huge payload.

My current implementation is like

```
reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(payloaD));
reader.beginObject();
    while(reader.hasNext()){
        String tokenName = reader.nextName();
        if("HEADER".equals(tokenName))
            //dosomething
        else if("DATA".equals(tokenName))
            //do something
        else
           //do something
     }
reader.endObject();
```

My implementation is assuming that I would process the JSON if header comes first, then data and the footer.

Thanks

Comment: Per JSON.org, An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma). It means, we can' rely on the ordering of the elements in an object.

Comment: With that, what is the alternative way to handle a huge payload, espicially if I had to enrich data with certain elements from header and footer , with out holding it in memory.

Comment: Does propOrder of JAXB has any effect on JSON representation